# How to Display Properties from Files with Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am using a files.list method like so,

```
function listFiles(){
    var sm = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'q': "properties has { key='input' and value ='" + document.getElementById('input').value + "'  and visibility='PUBLIC' } ",
          'spaces': 'drive'
          });
          request.execute(function(resp) {  
              document.write(resp.items);  
          });
}
```

but I want it to write out the item properties that have been assigned to the file. I am instead just getting [object, Object]. I understand why I am getting this but am unsure of how to actually print out the properties.

I have read the documentation however it is unclear, if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. change

```
document.write(resp.items);
```

into this

```
document.write(resp.items[0].whateverProperty);
```